# Print using epson esc/p2 on TM U325D

Tags: c#, printing

I would like to print a text in bold style using epson esc commands, however, when i use ESC F, i lose the first letter.

```
serialPort.Write(new char[] { (char)27, (char)69 }, 0, 2);
serialPort.Write("Line in bold");
```

I got:

**ine in bold**

I guess something is missing to send to the printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it work by changing the command, using the master selection of styles:

ESC ! n

Where n can be a sum of any of the next values:
0: 10 cpp
1: 12 cpp
2: proportional
4: condensed
8: bold
16: double pass
32: wide
64: italic
128: underline

```
serialPort.Write(new byte[] { 27, 33, 9 }, 0, 3);
```

So, 9 = 1 + 8: 10 cpp and bold.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use byte[]:

```
serialPort.Write(new byte[] { 27, 69 }, 0, 2);
serialPort.Write("Line in bold");
```

using char creates Unicode characters which are UTF16...

Comment: does not work, I get the same result, but better take off the cast.

Comment: I am no expert for epson... perhaps you are missing some byte the printer expects... try sending a third byte (for example a 32) after the 69...